# Apache permissions issue cant upload files

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, posix

I have recently built my first Debian 6 squeezebox as a LAMP server and all appear to be running fine. It is using the latest Mysql, PHP and Apache.. all installed using the apt-get command.

I have created several domains, and they are all running nicely (CMS systems) with one major exception.

I cannot use the CMS website functions to upload extensions or plugins without changing permissions to 777 first, and then dropping them back to 755 afterwards. Its almost as though the apache service is not running as root, or does not have permissions to the files.. and is more like a public user.

For my personal sites, I suppose this is borderline acceptable, but if I make a CMS for someone else, I cant have them unable to upload their own extensions.

Can anyone advise the best practice (happy to redo everything) for making sure the apache service has the full rights it needs to files and directories so I can leave permissions at 755.. or hell, even 604.

I have created a container in the root called www, and this directory contains a folder in the name of the domain i.e example.com, and in there are folders backup,logs,public.. the website files are in the public directory.

I have configured virtual name servers for all, and of course enabled the site.

Thank you in advance for any assitance

Comment: You never want Apache to run as root.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, careless comment.. but it is not running with any apparent authority at all.

Comment: What do your error logs say when you try to upload?

Comment: No error message, already 100% determined to be a permissions issue with the apache service. If I set permissions to 777 all is ok, anything else like 604 or even 775 leads to 'unable to copy file to this location' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho you need to create one *upload-directory*(say) under website public directory and set it's permission to 775..

second thing, the uploaded files might be first going */tmp*, so you need to move the uploaded file from there to *upload-directory*..do ensure that your file is getting successfully uploaded under /tmp first..

Comment: Yes but this is the problem.. I have tried setting to 775 and there is STILL a permissions problem. It is like the apache service is running with the permission 5. I need to make the apache service the owner, or at least in the group.

Comment: the ONLY way I can get the webservice to function properly in terms of being able to add plugins etc using the CMS functions is to set the whole website to 777

Comment: [as posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356167/apache-user-does-not-exist) try to check who owns the apache process and also try making nobody as the owner of your *upload-directory*

Answer (score 0):

For me (on Ubuntu) I had to add `umask 002` to `/etc/apache2/envvars` in order to get Wordpress to upload plugins/images with 775 permissions instead of 755 (i.e. allow anyone besides Apache and root to change the uploaded files)